Clockwise (counterclockwise) order of points in simple polygon
How to determine whether points of simple polygon are given in clockwise or counterclockwise orientation?
My idea was to use PositivelyOrientedPoints on successive three points. If there is more True-s the order is counterclockwise if there is more False-s the order is clockwise.
But my idea fails for some instances when there is equal number of True-s and False-s and the order in this case can be any of the two orientations.
On image top left is clockwise orientation because there is more false-s.
On image bottom left is counterclockwise orientation because there is more true-s.
On image top right is clockwise orientation but my test fails because there is equal number of false-s and true-s.
On image bottom right is counterclockwise orientation but my test fails because there is equal number of false-s and true-s.
Any idea what to do in indeterminate cases?
co1 = {{-2, 2}, {0, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, -1}, {0, 0}, {-2, -1}};
co2 = {{1, 2}, {-1, 4}, {-3, 1}, {-1, 2}, {-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}};
co3 = {{-2, 1}, {-1, 3}, {0, 0}, {2, -2}, {-1, -1}, {-4, -1}};
co4 = {{-1, 2}, {-3, 1}, {-1, 0}, {1, -2}, {1, 0}, {2, 4}};

Graphics[{Arrowheads[Large], Arrow /@ Partition[#, 2, 1, {1, 1}]}, 
    PlotLabel -> 
     Sort@Tally[
       PositivelyOrientedPoints /@ 
        Partition[#, 3, 1, {1, 1}]]] & /@ {co1, co2, co3, 
   co4} // Multicolumn




Use GeometricTest.
Table[GeometricTest[Polygon[co], "Clockwise"], {co, {co1, co2, co3, co4}}]
(* {True, False, True, False} *)


First time I encounter GeometricTest. Any idea how it works? If I wanted to avoid GeometricTest and do it by my own function.

OK, I see... it works also with symbolic input and it uses a lot of complicated inequalities. So maybe there is no simple method like I thought with PositivelyOrientedPoints.

You can do it yourself calculating the signed area and using Stokes' theorem. The sign gives the orientation. In compact form it can be written as: Table[Total[Det/@Partition[co,2,1,{1,1}]]<0,{co,{co1,co2,co3,co4}}]

Curve orientation, 2.07 How do I find the orientation of a simple polygon?.

test = WindingCount[Line[Append[#, First@#]], 
    RandomPoint@Polygon@#] &;
test /@ {co1, co2, co3, co4}


{-1, 1, -1, 1}

